# How to pass data-id and data-value from select option to laravel controller?

Tags: laravel

How can I pass data-id and data-value from option list to laravel controller.

```
<select class="form-control users" name="users" id="users">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Users</option>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        @if($user->type === 'something')
            <option value="{{$user->id}}"
                data-id="{{$user->type_id}}"
                data-value="{{$user->type}}">{{$user->something['name']}}
            </option>
        @endif
        @if($user->type === 'something2')
            <option value="{{$user->id}}"
                data-id="{{$user->type_id}}"
                data-value="{{$user->type}}">{{$user->something2['name']}}
            </option>
        @endif
        @if($user->type === 'something3')
            <option value="{{$user->id}}"
                data-id="{{$user->type_id}}"
                data-value="{{$user->type}}">{{$user->something3['name']}}
            </option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I have table name A where I want to store the value of data-id and data-value so I need to pass these values into laravel controller. How do I do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The content of the `value` attribute is the only thing that gets submitted from this form element. So put your data in there.

Comment: I need to save user->id as well user->type and user->type_id. Is there anyway I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by splitting your values via a special sign (i.e. - or @ or ~)

```
<option value="{{ $user->id }}-{{ $user->type_id }}-{{ $user->type }}"></option>
```

and when data gets submitted

```
$user = request()->input('users') or Input::get('users') or $_POST['users];
$user_data = explode('-', $user);
```

The above $user_data variable will give you respected data in 0, 1, and 2 keys.

So,

```
$user_id = $user_data[0];
$type_id = $user_data[1];
$type = $user_data[2];
```

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try.

Comment: I have done same as yours but it gives me data in this format "users" => "2-4-something", so can't do $user_id = $user_data[0].

Comment: You haven't done explode $user_data = explode('-', $user); , do this and it will work as I mentioned.

Comment: I did explode and also followed all the steps you mentioned but it didn't work.

Comment: If you explode any string then it results in array key values, so it is impossible except you would be making some other mistakes there. Can you print your full code here?