# Passing price of <select> to database - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database

I need to pass the data of the price to the database. But I have no idea how to do that without hidden inputs.

the ticket select:

```
<select name="ticket[{{$ticket->id}}]" class="p-2 bg-gray-100 rounded-lg" data-name="{{ $ticket->title }}" data-id="{{ $ticket->id }}" data-price="{{ $ticket->price }}" size="1" x-model="ticket" x-on:change="$store.tickets.add_ticket({{ $ticket->id }}, ticket)" @if ($event->bookable == '1') disabled @endif>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    @for ($i = $ticket->min; $i <= $ticket->max; $i++)
        <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
    @endfor
</select>
```

Input Form:

```
<input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="event_id" value="{{$event->id}}">
<input type="text" class="block w-full px-4 py-5 leading-tight text-gray-700 rounded-lg appearance-none bg-hartung-gray focus:ring focus:ring-primary/10 focus:outline-none" placeholder="Vorname*" name="firstname" pattern="[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ. -]+" required>
@if ($errors->has('firstname'))
    <div class="font-normal text-red-700">
        <p>Bitte geben Sie einen Vornamen ein.</p>
    </div>
@endif

<input type="text" class="block w-full px-4 py-5 leading-tight text-gray-700 rounded-lg appearance-none bg-hartung-gray focus:ring focus:ring-primary/10 focus:outline-none" placeholder="Nachname*" name="lastname" pattern="[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ. -]+" required>
@if ($errors->has('lastname'))
    <div class="font-normal text-red-700">
        <p>Bitte geben Sie eine Nachnamen ein.</p>
    </div>
@endif

<input type="email" class="block w-full px-4 py-5 leading-tight text-gray-700 rounded-lg appearance-none bg-hartung-gray focus:ring focus:ring-primary/10 focus:outline-none" placeholder="E-Mail*" name="email" required>
@if ($errors->has('email'))
    <div class="font-normal text-red-700">
        <p>Bitte geben Sie eine E-Mail ein.</p>
    </div>
@endif

<input type="tel" class="block w-full px-4 py-5 leading-tight text-gray-700 rounded-lg appearance-none bg-hartung-gray focus:ring focus:ring-primary/10 focus:outline-none" placeholder="Telefonnummer*" name="phone" pattern="[0-9 (.)+]{3,15}" required>
@if ($errors->has('phone'))
    <div class="font-normal text-red-700">
        <p>Bitte geben Sie einen Telefonnummer ein.</p>
    </div>
@endif
```

**Controller**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\CheckoutConfirmation;
use App\Mail\CheckoutInformation;
use App\Models\Checkout;
use App\Models\Events;
use App\Models\OrderedTickets;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class EventsCheckoutController extends Controller
{
    public function getCheckout($slug)
    {
        
        // get the course data from the database
        $event = Events::query()
            ->where('url', '=', $slug)
            ->first();

        // pass the data to the correct view
        return view('pages.checkout.checkout', [
            "event" => $event
        ]);
    }


    // Store Contact Form data
    public function placeOrder(Request $request) {

        // Form validation
        $this->validate($request, [
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'dancepartner' => ''
        ]);


        //  Store data in database
        $checkout = new Checkout();
        $checkout->event_id = $request->event_id;
        $checkout->quantity = array_sum($request->ticket);
        $checkout->firstname = $request->firstname;
        $checkout->lastname = $request->lastname;
        $checkout->email = $request->email;
        $checkout->phone = $request->phone;
        $checkout->save();

        // set the UUID
        $uuid = $checkout->id;

        foreach ($request->get('ticket') as $id => $quantity)
        {
            if ($quantity > 0) {
                $ordered_ticket = new OrderedTickets();
                $ordered_ticket->checkout_id = $uuid;
                $ordered_ticket->ticket_id = $id;
                $ordered_ticket->quantity = $quantity;
                $ordered_ticket->amount = 100;
                $ordered_ticket->save();
            }
        }

        // send confirmation email to customer
        Mail::to($request->email)->send(new CheckoutConfirmation($checkout));
        // send confirmation email to company
        Mail::to($request->email)->send(new CheckoutInformation($request));


        // redirect to confirmation page with UUID
        return redirect()->to('/checkout/confirmation/'. $uuid);
    }
}
```

**How it works:**

There are events, each of them can have multiple tickets.They each have a different id. `$ticket->id`
They can also have different prices `$ticket->price`

What I need to do is pass the price of the selected tickets into the database. You can see that the `$ordered_ticket->amount = 100;` is currently hardcoded.

So a user selects a ticket:
Example Ticket 1 - 200€ (amount: 3)
Example Ticket 2 - 100€ (amount: 2)

the Ticket 1 needs to have 600€ and the Ticket 2 needs to have 200€ saved to the database. Then the total pricing of all tickets would need to be saved onto the database like this:

```
array_sum($request->price); // example
```

**This is the database structure:**
[image]

This is the request `dd($request)`:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this [How to pass data-id and data-value from select option to laravel controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570264/how-to-pass-data-id-and-data-value-from-select-option-to-laravel-controller)

Based on this SO posting I changed my controller to the following:

```
//  Store data in database
    $checkout = new Checkout();
    $checkout->event_id = $request->event_id;
    $checkout->quantity = array_sum($request->ticket);
    $checkout->firstname = $request->firstname;
    $checkout->lastname = $request->lastname;
    $checkout->email = $request->email;
    $checkout->phone = $request->phone;
    foreach ($request->get('ticket') as $id => $quantity) {
        if ($quantity > 0) {
            $ticketInfo = explode('-', $quantity);
            $total[] = $ticketInfo[0] * $ticketInfo[1];
        }
    }
    $checkout->total = array_sum($total);
    $checkout->save();

    // set the UUID
    $uuid = $checkout->id;

    foreach ($request->get('ticket') as $id => $quantity)
    {
        $ticketInfo = explode('-', $quantity);
        // [0] = quantity [1] = amount

        if ($quantity > 0) {
            $ordered_ticket = new OrderedTickets();
            $ordered_ticket->checkout_id = $uuid;
            $ordered_ticket->ticket_id = $id;
            $ordered_ticket->quantity = $ticketInfo[0];
            $ordered_ticket->amount = $ticketInfo[0] * $ticketInfo[1];
            $ordered_ticket->save();
        }
    }
```

and the `<select>` to this:

```
<select name="ticket[{{$ticket->id}}]" class="p-2 bg-gray-100 rounded-lg" data-name="{{ $ticket->title }}" data-id="{{ $ticket->id }}" data-price="{{ $ticket->price }}" size="1" x-model="ticket" x-on:change="$store.tickets.add_ticket({{ $ticket->id }}, ticket)" @if ($event->bookable == '1') disabled @endif>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    @for ($i = $ticket->min; $i <= $ticket->max; $i++)
        <option value="{{ $i }}-{{$ticket->price}}">{{ $i }}</option>
    @endfor
</select>
```

TLDR:
Passing the data inside the `value=""` of the `<option>` gives the option to pass multiple values, if seperated with an `-`.

**UPDATE:**
It is very important that if it is done this way it is needed to verify the validity of the data that gets passed. The better way would be to use the `name="ticket[{{$ticket->id}}]"`.

And do something like this:

```
foreach ($request->get('ticket') as $id => $quantity)
{
    if ($quantity > 0) {
        $ticket = DB::table('tickets')
            ->where('id', '=', $id)
            ->first();
        $ordered_ticket = new OrderedTickets();
        $ordered_ticket->checkout_id = $uuid;
        $ordered_ticket->ticket_id = $id;
        $ordered_ticket->quantity = $quantity;
        $ordered_ticket->amount = $ticket->price * $quantity;
        $ordered_ticket->save();
    }
}
```

this way the verification of the data would be much easier!